# Android Imagebutton focus glow / color tint

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

So, when using a ImageButton with

```
android:background="@drawable/icon"
```

defined by default the glow on focus / press effect that comes with every default android button is missing. I'm aware of that i might use a selector to use different images on different states, but thats not what android does and thats not what i'm looking for.

i want android to add the **default** outer glow effect to my imagebutton when i focus / press it.
i think (maybe its done a different way, dunno!) android is using tint for that. however. using a tint selector and defineing it like this:

```
android:tint="@color/tint_selector"
```

corrupted my app. using a static color as tint did not corrupt it BUT no tint was visible.

so my questions:

1. how does android do that glow
2. if its done using tint, how to define a tint selector that works with API 7 and > for a imagebutton and how should the selector look like for different colors in different states?
3. if its done using tint, is there a static resource i can use so i get the "default glow color" so i got the **default** glow color on every android API? something like @color/glow ?

Comment: You are just trying to make the image button glow?

Comment: glow onClick and glow onFocus, yes.

Answer (score 0):

It is in fact done with drawable selectors. It's not outer, just the 9patch is smaller when in the unselected state.

Comment: any source for that? i cant belive its using 9patch.
the glow i'm talking about is also present outer all input fields when focused for example.

Comment: in fact, after looking more at it, this is not right. a simple example: create a new app and declare a application icon. within the app-drawer you get the glow WITHOUT having a 9patch declared. However, for my needs i found that its enough to use a ImageButton with my icon as src and a selector as background.